# Create a class proxy within a castle windsor facility

Tags: c#, castle-windsor, facilities

I'm trying to create a facility that will add some interceptor to the registered class based on the class attribute.
This is my facility:

```
public class MyFacility : AbstractFacility
{
     protected override void Init()
    {
        this.Kernel.ComponentRegistered += (s, h) =>
        {
            if (h.ComponentModel.Implementation.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MyAttribute), false).Length > 0)
            {
                h.ComponentModel.Interceptors.Add(InterceptorReference.ForType<MyInterceptor>());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but this way, when I use the `this` keyword in a class method it refers to the target class not the proxy class and this makes some framework that I use don't work properly.

I need to create with a facility the same proxy that is generated with the `ProxyGenerator.CreateClassProxy<MyClass>()` method.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Could you show more code? Is the component you are registering an interface or a class?

Comment: the componenti I'm registering is an interface.
Thi is the windsor installation:
_wc = new WindsorContainer();

_wc.AddFacility<Facility>();

_wc.Register(
  Component.For<Authorize>()
);

_wc.Register(
  Component.For<IService>().
  ImplementedBy<Service>()
);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expose the class as a service on your component.

```
container.Register(
   Component.For<SomeClass,ISomeInterface>().Lifestyle.Whatever.Interceptors<SomeInterceptor>()
);
```

Comment: how can i expose the class as a service? can you post an example please?